# Navigation in a TileMap with 2 types of tile in 1 cell in Godot4

Tags: procedural-generation, path-finding, tilemap, tiles, godot-4

I'm stuck with the navigation in a `TileMap` based scenario in Godot 4. My intention is to make the enemy (boats) to chase the player while avoiding procedurally generated islands.

It's possible to have 2 types of tile in the same cell, one navigable, the other not, and make the not navigable one prevail over the other?

My `TileMap` node has a `TileSet` of cell size 16x16, 2 layers (water and ground) and 1 terrain (sand_on_water). They have 1 `Navigation Layer` painted in the water tiles, the only ones I want the enemies to go. Here's how it's generated:

```
func generate_map() -> void:
    var beach_tiles := []
    for y in range(-MAP_SIZE.y * 0.5, MAP_SIZE.y * 0.5):
        for x in range(-MAP_SIZE.x * 0.5, MAP_SIZE.x * 0.5):
            var current_coord := Vector2i(x, y)
            var water_tile_coords := Vector2i(0, 0)
            # water
            tile_map.set_cell(WATER_LAYER, current_coord, SOURCE_ID, water_tile_coords)
            # ground
            if noise.get_noise_2d(x, y) > 0.4:
                beach_tiles.push_back(current_coord)
    # terrain connect
    tile_map.set_cells_terrain_connect(GROUND_LAYER, beach_tiles, TERRAIN_SET_0, SAND_ON_WATER)
```

Basically put water tiles (WATER_LAYER) in all cells and then, if noise wants, add sand tiles (GROUND_LAYER) **on top of the water ones** from the terrain set so they conform corners and so.

If I launch the game with the debug mode on in the `NavigationAgent2D`, the enemies try to reach the player as if there was no obstacles in the way. Their paths go straight through islands and they get stuck by the physical layer. I think the bottom water tile says it's navigable, and the upper sand tile, which is not navigable, gets ignored.

The tileset (png) I've drawn has the sand tiles with transparent parts so, for example, if I change the color of the water tiles, I don't have to paint the new water color on the sand tiles.

If I don't place water tiles below sand tiles, the enemies behave like expected, avoiding obstacles. But I've designed my sand tiles to have water tiles below. If they don't, black parts are rendered.

Is there any trick in Godot4 to solve this problem? Or I just have to add water parts painted into my sand tiles and avoid placing water tiles below them?